# How to install symform.deb?

Tags: apt

I've an updated Ubuntu 13.10 and I want to install the .deb from Symform (a cloud NAS service). But I'm having problems when I download the .deb and installing it from their website http://www.symform.com/download/.

Is there an `apt-get` for Symform in any repo?

Why is the .deb giving the following error when I `sudo dkpg -i Symform.deb`? It keeps on printing the certificate...

```
alvas@ubi:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i Symform.deb 
[sudo] password for alvas: 
Selecting previously unselected package symform.
(Reading database ... 598899 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking symform (from Symform.deb) ...
Setting up symform (3.19.7-1) ...
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

1 certificate(s) added to store Trust.
Mono Certificate Manager - version 3.2.7.0
Manage X.509 certificates and CRL from stores.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

^Cdpkg: error processing symform (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script was interrupted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 symform
```

Comment: I believe it's a problem with their package postinst script. Is a real pain to debug it. They should fix their stuff. You can try and check the output of `sh -x /var/lib/dpkg/info/symform.postinst configure` but I don't make promises. As I said before, this is a problem with their package, a bug more accurately, and should be fixed by them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you entered ^C to exit the process.  It may work if you let it run for a while.  The "1 certificate(s) added..." blocks are normal for the Symform install and the result of adding certificates to the mono cert store one at a time.  This will take a little time as there are many of them.

Comment: yes, you were right =)

Comment: There are changes in the pipeline to eliminate "one at a time" nature and speed up the install time drastically.  They will be available in an update in the near future.